# How do I most efficiently return multiple values from an overloaded operator? (C++)

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a class "complex" that contains a Real and an Imaginary value. I'm trying to overload the + operator so I can add real to real and imaginary to imaginary, but I'm banging my head against a wall here.

In the function, I can get the values easy. Returning them however, is a bitch.

My plan is to overload the '=' operator, too, so I can go

complex a, b, c;

(set a and b)

c = a + b;

then have a+b return a complex, then have complex c equal the complex returned by a+b

Any opinion on whether that's a viable path?

Any opinion on whether it can be done easier?

Answer (score 2):

Return them as a `complex`!  e.g.

```
const complex operator+(const complex &a, const complex &b)
{
    return complex(a.re + b.re, a.im + b.im);
}
```

You shouldn't need to overload `operator=`; the compiler will generate one for you that does an element-by-element copy, which will probably suffice for a complex class.

Comment: `operator+`, for cleanliness, should be implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

Comment: @GMan: Indeed. The above is just an example to demonstrate feasibility.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Do you have a `complex` class?

```
struct complex
{
    complex(float real, float imag) :
    real(real), imag(imag)
    {}

    // first make the mutating version
    complex& operator+=(const complex& rhs)
    {
        real += rhs.real; 
        imag += rhs.imag;

        return *this;
    }

    float real, imag;
};

// then use that for the non-mutating version
complex operator+(complex lhs, const complex& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

This is, of course, just an exercise; we have [`std::complex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/).

Comment: I know about the built-in complex. This is, indeed, an exercise. Our teacher is requiring us to write our own, and I'm having a little trouble getting *-+/ to work with it.

Comment: @SR: Is there anything in this answer that confuses you? This method is the most modern practice.

Comment: Mostly "Why is it a struct?" I'm pretty sure I get the overloaded operators

Comment: @SR: I dunno, because it can be. You can make it `class` if you want, they're the same thing. `class` just defaults to private on inheritance and accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with overloading the + operator:

```
complex operator+(const complex& a, const complex& b) const {
    return complex(a.real + b.real, a.imag + b.imag);
}
```

And the operator=() similarly? (but the compiler give you this by default)

```
complex& operator=(const complex& a) {
    real = a.real;
    imag = a.imag;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Probably nothing. I'm mostly looking to find out if overloading the = operator is the way to go or if there's a better way I've missed.

Comment: @Oli: It shouldn't. While that seems to make sense (after all, `2 + 2` has a constant result), you just ruin optimization opportunities when it comes to C++0x rvalues, IIRC.

Comment: @GMan: I'm not particularly familiar with C++0x.  What sort of opportunities?

Comment: @Oli: Let's say your class has move-semantics, if your operator returns a `const`, it cannot bind to an rvalue reference, so will be copied instead of moved into its destination. (Like `std::string` and `operator+`, for example.)

Comment: maybe not the return value, but I bet the arguments can be `const&`. You're not going to modify them. +1 though :)

Answer (score 0):

It is viable but there is already [complex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/) class in standard library. Reuse it or at least have a look how the operator overloading is done there.